# Should i create a Core library for all business applications ? or each one individual?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, object-oriented-design, .net, n-tier

**I was find many companies which creating entities and models for each business applications**

So all these apps not reusable.

Now, some clients of the company for example. needs 3 kind of software.

For example [ HR management, Inventory, and Asset management ]

Here's a problems i found.

1. if i created each project from scratch it will take many time.
2. each project can't be reusable. so i can't create asset from Inventory project.

So I need to know following :

1. Should i create a Single Core library which contains Data-Entry controls and so that i can import it in each project ?
2. A Single Core will make me don't create any new data-entry or addons controls. so i just drag & drop and create a Business App that i need directly. without creating a Models for it. Assuming i Use a Custom Control which have dynamic properties that take ( TableID, FieldID's from currently working Form or screen )

Please, i don't ask because i don't know exactly what done. but i need to hear from People who works in Mid-Scale Business Apps or Large Scale one.

In breifly. Guess that your client asking to make 7 Business Apps. that is separately .

Ex : Financial System, Inventory, HR Management, and so ? now all of them is Data-Entry screens and reports.

What exactly will you thinking or do? to gain more time. and reusable components?

Comment: https://thedailywtf.com/articles/Patterns-of-Failure

Answer (score 3):

Creating frameworks and reusable components takes time and a lot of experience, and often several iterations of production use and redesign based on user feedback. You should not assume that you can save time by writing a library of components at the start.

Instead, start with just one application, modularize it properly so that you can extract reusable parts and put them into a library, then use that library to write the next application and possibly refactor the first one (if there are substantial advantages to gain).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. but the already created apps is not good enough. and it requires to learn specific programming language such as Oddo requires a Python. why a man who worked in his language convert to Python. this is example. and all other apps also requires to learn new tools. that is specific and more deeply than your needs.

Comment: Am speaking about general-purpose  of small business softwares. such as POS why each time people creating everything from scratch. why not re-use the controls for example ( SearchBoxes that attached with DB, and Grids which supports enter presses and validations ) why Should Scratch and scratch again. how to overcome this ?.

Comment: So what is the actual problem that you want to solve? A real programming task that you want to perform? Or do you want to find a solution for everyone else who does not reuse stuff but should? As it is, your question sounds more like a rant about how bad the world is than like a genuine request for advice about a concrete problem.

Comment: The big takeaway is to modularize your single application from the get go in such a way that it is easy to extract components if/when you have a need to reuse them in the future.

Comment: Hans.  I mean shortly. the best approach when you creating 6 or 7 apps with same GUI and controls for example. what you will do ? create a single controls for search, grid, etc for each app ? or create a Core Lib which are reusable.. THANKS again )

Comment: As I wrote in my answer, the best approach is to start with one app, not all at once. Write the parts that are likely reusable in a modular way, so that it is easy to extract them into a Core Lib when you create it. But write the components along with the application in which they are used, not upfront before you start with the applications.

Comment: Ahh, you mean creating application first then convert some Controls to reusable components ? is that what i get a true ?  Thanks again :)

Comment: Yes that's the basic idea.